# Problem with css position:fixed during scrolling

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, fixed

i'm working on a school project and i'm having trouble fixing the bottom for the slider I created near it.
The problem is that when i scroll the page they scroll with it, even if I use position:fixed on css. (Hope I explained it well)
Thank you very much to those will help me!

```css
.carousel-container {
  padding-top: 6%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 720px;
  width: 1080px;
  transform: none;
}

.carousel-slide {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
}

#prevButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nextButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Galleria">
  <div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672647.jpg" id="lastclone">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672645.jpg">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672643.jpg">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672648.jpg">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672647.jpg">
      <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672645.jpg" id="firstclone">
    </div>
    <input id="nextButton" type="image" name="Name of image button" src="Icone\SliderNext.svg" alt="PrevButton">
    <input id="prevButton" type="image" name="Name of image button" src="Icone\SliderPrevious.svg" alt="NextButton">
  </div>
  <hr style="width:50%; position:relative; margin:auto; margin-top:5%;  border-color:#000000;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

they scrolle with it because you give them a specific height and width so when the height is > 750px so the place of the div will end their .I just set the galleria div like a container so all the elements are inside of it so it will be like a card so the elements inside of it will be fixed ; you can try this code :

```css
      .Galleria{
       width:100vw;
       height:100vh;
       position:relative;



       .carousel-container{
        padding-top: 6%;
        margin:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:720px;
        width:1080px;
        transform: none;
       position:fixed;
    }
    .carousel-slide{
    
        display:flex;
        width: 100%;
        height:720px;
    }

    #prevButton{
        position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        z-index:10;
        left:10%;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    #nextButton{
        position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        z-index:10;
        right:10%;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="Galleria">
        <div class="carousel-container">
          <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img class="galleria"  src="thumb-1920-672647.jpg" id="lastclone">
            <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672645.jpg">
            <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672643.jpg">
            <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672648.jpg">
            <img class="galleria"  src="thumb-1920-672647.jpg">
            <img class="galleria" src="thumb-1920-672645.jpg" id="firstclone">
          </div>
            <input id="nextButton" type="image" name="Name of image button" src="Icone\SliderNext.svg"  
            alt="PrevButton">
            <input id="prevButton" type="image" name="Name of image button" src="Icone\SliderPrevious.svg"  
            alt="NextButton">
        </div>
       <hr style="width:50%; position:relative; margin:auto; margin-top:5%;  border-color:#000000;">
    </div>
```